# What are the characteristics of slang, dialect and colloquial speech?

Tags: differences

**What are the different aspects  of slang, dialect and colloquial speech?

Answer (score 2):

*Slang*:

A kind of language occurring chiefly in casual and playful speech, made up typically of short-lived coinages and figures of speech that are deliberately used in place of standard terms for added raciness, humor, irreverence, or other effects.
*Grass is slang for marijuana*

*Dialect*:

A regional or social variety of a language distinguished by pronunciation, grammar, or vocabulary, especially a variety of speech differing from the standard literary language or speech pattern of the culture in which it exists: *Cockney is a dialect of English*

*Colloquial speech*:

refer to types of speech or to usages that are not on a formal level. colloquial is often mistakenly used with a connotation of disapproval, as if it meant “vulgar” or “bad” or “incorrect” usage, whereas it merely describes a casual or familiar style used in speaking and writing: colloquial expressions. conversational refers to a style used in the oral exchange of ideas, opinions, etc.: The newsletter was written in an easy conversational style. informal means without formality, without strict attention to set forms, unceremonious; it describes the ordinary, everyday language of cultivated speakers: *Informal English*